# How to encode a path containing spaces in a CFStringRef

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to use the FSEvent API to watch a folder for changes in cocoa. My implementation works well as long as the provided folder has a name without spaces.

So far I could not figure out how to make a proper CFStringRef that points to a folder with spaces in its name.

Attempts so far (none of them worked):

```
CFStringRef fpath = CFSTR("/Applications/Program With Spaces.app/Contents/Whatever");

CFStringRef fpath = CFSTR("/Applications/Program\\ With\\ Spaces.app/Contents/Whatever");

fpath = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes (NULL,
                                                 fpath,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

The rest of the code is as in the API docs:

```
CFArrayRef pathsToWatch = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **)&fpath, 1, NULL);
stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                                 &mycallback,...
```

Please help how to properly assign a folder with spaces in its name. Thanks.

Comment: This is as simple as this : `NSString *url = @"/Application/Images/anoop tour to Australia";
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`

Comment: That does not work :( I converted it to cfstringref with a simple bridge cast.

Comment: I would have expected that the first variant (just spaces in the path, no percent escaping) works.

Comment: You don't need escaping `FSEventStreamCreate` works with file system paths, not URLs.

Comment: Interestingly it works on another computer without escaping but not on mine. Both 10.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a bug in FSEvent that happens rarely with certain folders. So far I could not find a reliable solution.